# Переопределение шаблона EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net, шаблоны

Создал шаблон Shared -> EditorTemplates -> StringGeneralTemplate.cshtml.
Но некоторые поля должны быть disabled, а некоторые нет. Создавать новый шаблон из-за одного атрибута этого глупо (как по мне). Можно ли каким-то образом посылать запрос на дополнительные атрибуты в мой шаблон? Т.е. сделать это опциональным?

Пример моего шаблона:

```
@model string

<div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 3px;">
    <span class="td col-md-3"><label>@Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.ShortDisplayName</label></span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="@Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" id="@Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName" value="@Html.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать несколькими способами.

### Вариант 1

В методе `EditorFor` можно передать дополнительные данные (здесь это третий аргумент):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.TestProperty, "StringGeneralTemplate", new { disabled = true });
```

В шаблоне эти данные извлекаем через словарь `ViewData` и обрабатываем:

```
@model string

@{
    var disabled = ViewData["disabled"] as bool?;

    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        { "class", "form-control" }
    };

    // если дополнительные данные переданы
    if (disabled.HasValue && disabled.Value) {
        attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
    }
}

// ...

// Создаем input для свойства модели с нужными атрибутами
@Html.TextBox(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName, Model, attributes)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model)
```

### Вариант 2

Если факт того, что поле должно быть выключено, известен на этапе компиляции, то дополнительные данные можно передать в атрибуте `AdditionalMetadata` у свойства модели:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DisplayName("Test property")]
    [AdditionalMetadata("disabled", true)]
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }

// ...
```

В шаблоне дополнительные данные получаем через `ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues`:

```
bool? disabled = null;
if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("disabled")) {
    disabled = ViewData.ModelMetadata.AdditionalValues["disabled"] as bool?;
}

// Остальной код аналогичен предыдущему варианту
```

Comment: а можно же сразу во  ViewData добавить? Куча кода уберется. Сейчас попробовал, добавил ViewData.Add("class", "form-control") и все работает. Просто может тут есть подводные камни, которые я не вижу ?

Comment: @user2867221 да, действительно. Если через ViewData ничего кроме атрибутов для инпута не передавать, то никаких проблем.